# Send Keystrokes via telnet

Tags: c, linux, unix, telnet, keystroke

How to send multiple keystrokes via telnet. In daily routine, I connect to a server which accept "ESC+3" and "ESC+E" like keystrokes. Now I am trying to automate the process using some programs. For that I have to give keystrokes via programatically. If it is a single line command means, it doesn't make that much complex. But the application expect keystrokes also. So, is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Some code would probably help understanding what you mean.

Comment: @FelixPalmen `write(fd,"hai",4);` Here "Hai" is a data which is sent to server. But instead of hai, now I want to give "ESC+E".

Comment: So you just need to know how to express ESC in a c string literal: `\x1b`

Comment: Yeah... you are right. Like "\n" for enter. And ESC is combined with one more key.

Comment: @FelixPalmen `\x1b` is for esc?

Answer (score 2):

`ESC` is just a normal (non printable) character with ASCII code `0x1b`. So, if you have an open file descriptor `fd` to your service, for sending `ESC+E` the following will do:

```
write(fd, "\x1bE", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For interactive ttys, there is a program called `expect`.  I haven't used it for a long time, but I was able to find this link: https://www.lifewire.com/linus-unix-command-expect-2201096.

It'll do what you want, I think.  It was originally written in TCL (back before Linux was invented).  There might be newer versions in something like Python, or some such.

Here's the "blurb":

```
INTRODUCTION

Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what
can be expected from a program and what the correct response
should be. An interpreted language provides branching and
high-level control structures to direct the dialogue.
```